# Perl (compare two file) print out differences on main file only

Tags: perl

I have a two file that I need to compare and print out difference found on the first key file.  File one is the key file contains customer phone numbers, with file letter signifying the type is C- CELLPHONE or H-HOMEPHONE. The first letter is irrelevant.

```
C2817771111 MARY LEE
C8328883333 JOSEPH NGO
C2012122111 PETER LANDRY
C2123461111 PETER JAMES
C2531861212 DAMARIS PAUL
H8329195253 TIMOTHY HUE
```

The second files has more columns but with but the file two columns are identical

```
C8328883333  JOSEPH NGO    ADDRESS CITY STATE COUNTRY
C2012122111 PETER LANDRY ADDRESS CITY STATE  COUNTRY
C2123461111 PETER JAMES   ADDRESS CITY STATE  COUNTRY

#! /usr/bin/env perl
my %custphonehash = ();
$cellphone = "<cellphone.dat";
open (HOMEPHONES,"<homephone.txt");
open(CELLPHONES,$cellphone);
open(DELTA_RECORDS,">delta_phones.txt");
  while(<CELLPHONES>){
   chomp($cellphone =  $_);
   $custouthash{$cellphone} = substr($cellphone,1,10);
    }
    while(<HOMEPHONES>) {
     chomp($line =  $_);
    $phone_no = ($line,1,10)  

     if ( exists $custphonehash{$phone_no} 
     {
     print DELTA_RECORDS "$_\n" ;

     }

      }
   close CELLPHONES;
   close HOMEPHONES;
   close DELTA_RECORDS;*
```

Output should be like:

```
C2531861212 DAMARIS PAUL
H8329195253 TIMOTHY HUE
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a hash table of the items from the second file, then you can iterate over the first file and check if that number exists, and also if the name matches the number.

Given FILE1 looks like this

```
C2817771111 MARY LEE
C8328883333 JOSEPH NGO
C2012122111 PETER LANDRY
C2123461111 PETER JAMES
C2531861212 DAMARIS PAUL
H8329195253 TIMOTHY HUE
```

and FILE2 looks like this

```
C8328883333  JOSEPH NGO    ADDRESS CITY STATE COUNTRY
C2012122111 PETER LANDRY ADDRESS CITY STATE  COUNTRY
C2123461111 PETER JAMES   ADDRESS CITY STATE  COUNTRY
```

and script looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/[CH](\d+) +(\w+ +\w+) *.*/;
my %hash;
while (<FILE2>) {
    my ($num, $name) = $_ =~ $regex;
    $hash{$num} = "$name";
}

while (<FILE1>) {
    my ($num, $name) = $_ =~ $regex;
    print unless (exists $hash{$num} and $hash{$num} = $name)
}
```

I get the following output

```
C2817771111 MARY LEE
C2531861212 DAMARIS PAUL
H8329195253 TIMOTHY HUE
```

Get into the habit of always using the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas as they will help scope your code correctly and pick up errors.

Also, the current idiom for opening files is to use lexical filehandles, with three arguments, like so...

```
open my $homephone, '<', 'homephone.txt';
while (<$homephone>) {
    # do stuff
}
close $homephone
```